# Multiple checkbox values into database looping

Tags: php

trying to insert multiple values in my mySQL database this is what I've got so far.

```
if (in_array(",", $_POST['categories'])) { /* Other was selected */}
        $cat = implode(" ,", $_POST['categories']);
        if (in_array(",", $_POST['subcat'])) { /* Other was selected */}
        $sub = implode(" ,", $_POST['subcat']);
        if (in_array(",", $_POST['type'])) { /* Other was selected */}
        $type = implode(" ,", $_POST['type']);
        if (in_array(",", $_POST['payment'])) { /* Other was selected */}
        $payment = implode(" ,", $_POST['payment']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_locations SET

                name='".$_POST['name']."', 
                alias='".$_POST['alias']."',
                category_id='$cat',
                subcategory_id='$sub',
                tourism_type_id='$type',
                lgu_id='$payment',
                latitude='".$_POST['latbox']."', 
                longitude='".$_POST['lngbox']."'
            ";
        $qry= mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        if ($qry)
        {   
            header("location:addsuccess.php");
            exit();
        }
```

As you can see there are not just 1 multiple entries but 4. . . would appreciate on how to proceed on this. ..  also my form all has `name=name[]` so no problems on the form. It just inserts single values into my db rather than multiple.

Comment: Lookup SQL injection. This is very, very insecure code.

Comment: Yep. Read about. But this is just a practice site.

Comment: Practice `mysqli_` or `PDO` then; not deprecated functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your application is your database design. If you can have multiple categories, types, payments, etc. then you need a relational model that can handle this. One way of doing this would be to have one table that handles your requests, then child tables for categories, types, payments, etc of each request.

```
> requests table

id date
1  2012-01-25

> categories table

request_id category
1          1
1          2
```

And so on.